# Transpose and repeat column header on rows

Tags: excel, header, row, transpose

I've got a list with a huge amount of columns. I want to repeat the column header on each row and put all the columns into just two.

I start with this:

[image]

The result should be:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea if how I can do this? Thanks

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using??

Comment: Do you have power query? what you need is unpivot

Comment: No I dont, Might have to take a look at that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Person1` is in A1, insert and label a new ColumnA then unpivot (eg as described in detail under [Convert matrix to 3-column table ('reverse pivot', 'unpivot', 'flatten', 'normalize')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal/20543651#20543651) and filter to delete rows blank under `Value`.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this using a method described here: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2461-excel-reverse-pivot-table.html